# Draw rectangles with transparency

Tags: php, image

How can I draw multiple rectangles with transparency? My code is below.

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);
//$img =imagecreatefromjpeg("water.jpg");
$imageX = imagesx($img);
$imageY = imagesy($img);
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255,255,255, 127);
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 000,255,255);
imagefilledrectangle($img, 10, 10, $imageX-10, $imageY-10, $transparent);
//imagealphablending($img, true);
imagerectangle($img, 50, 50, 150, 150, $white);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
//imagepng($img,'anand.png');
```

Comment: where is your code ? what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Please, post your code again

Comment: No, your code is not below.

Comment: Maybe the code is transparent as well.

Answer (score 1):

See [imagecolorallocatealpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php). According to the documentation:

> imagecolorallocatealpha() behaves identically to imagecolorallocate() with the addition of the transparency parameter alpha.

Simply replace `imagecolorallocate` with `imagecolorallocatealpha`, specifying the opacity for the color as the last parameter with a value from 0 to 127 (where 0 is fully opaque and 127 is fully transparent)

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay, But i want draw multiple rectangles  transparent but in my case except one rectangle no other rectangles got transparent.  can you send code

Comment: @Dilu, note how your `$white` variable is using `imagecolorallocate` and not `imagecolorallocatealpha`.